# Finding Java Memory Leak (with JNA)

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, jna

My Java application seems to have a memory leak. It is the first time for me dealing with something like that. Im not using pure Java but also JNA to use user32 functionality. 
I noticed that when  my program runs for a longer time, like one hour, the memory that its process needs keeps growing. It is like 100Mb when I start it and it ended up like being over 1Gb after one hour.

I noticed this using the windows task manager. When I started to investigate this, I used profilers like visualvm and JProfiler. Both showed me a heap usage of about 150mb and some 20mb of PermGen space, all while the windows task manager clearly showed me that it uses up about 1Gb. So I figured that the problem must be in the native heap, which both visualvm and JProfiler seem to be unable to access/profile. I created heap dumps and memory snapshots and analysed them with visualvm and MAT. The biggest objects (and their retained sizes) never exeeded 4Mb - I am no expert at all, but this does not seem very leaky/not too big for me. Plus when I garbage collect by hand (using the profilers) the used java heap got smaller as expected, but the overall consumption of the process stayed at 1Gb. This findings also lead me to the conclusion that the problem is not within the Java heap space.

So I think the JNA calls cause this problems. But unfortunately I have no clue how to solve this matter, as I can not simply not use JNA. I read tons of articels about memory leaks, most of them which are related to jave almost always ignore the native heap. The ones that don't (e.g. the oracle article) tell me that I can not simply use one of the native profiling methods because they misinterpret java code and lead to wrong conclusions. Oracle suggests "libumem.so", but this seems to be usable on solaris systems only.

So my overall question is - could somebody give me any hint on what to do? What tools can I use?

But maybe the problem is simply me not using JNA properly. According to this: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jna-users/Xy7Sm8Fb-Gc
and from what I read and understood from several text snippets from stackoverflow, the jna documentation and random articels on the internet is that JNA will release the memory it allocates and the allocated memory on the java side will be garbage collected. So when I do the following:

```
    //I want to get text (as a String) of a handle
    public static String getTextOfHWND(HWND hwnd)
    {
      //allocate the space for the string
    byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
    //let user32 method fill me the byte array with the needed information
    User32.INSTANCE.SendMessageA(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, 100, windowText);
    //let Native convert this to a String I can use in Java
    String whatWasFound = Native.toString(windowText);


    return whatWasFound;
    }
```

... the "byte[] windowText" variable (the allocated memory for it) should be freed by the GC, the same should be valid for the String I get ("whatWasFound"). Is that correct? Do I need to free something by hand in this example? I can see that Native offers a free method for Buffers (but unfortunately not for arrays). What is happening on the native side, is something getting allocated there and is it released afterwards?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is something like `User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowText(hwnd, charBuf, charBuf.length);` that eliminates the need for messages. `charBuf` is `char[]`. I'm not sure but it might be more unicode-safe.

Comment: I have such a case too where I keep giving a 32 MiB byte[] to a dll function that fills it with data (sort of like yours) and got out of memory after 60000 calls or so. I'm not even sure it's the root cause at all since I can't reliably reproduce it. I changed the method declaration to accept `Memory` instead but haven't had the change to test it in practice. When a new dev version gets released and people used it for a while, then we can know for sure whether this WASN'T the problem (need to look further...), or that it still might be (no more crash, so lets keep Memory).

Comment: @Mark Jeronimus  I know about GetWindowText, but it does not work as good as this version for child handles. At least in the context I am using it. The question would remain - what happens with the charBuf memory? I will try using Memory instead of byte[], lets see if it changes anything. Thanks for the  suggestion.

Comment: Look for places in your code where you're calling a native method that returns a buffer or other native-allocated memory.  Anything you create on the Java side (`Memory` or `byte[]`) will be garbage-collected when it is no longer referenced.  Any memory JNA allocates for its own use (structures, string arrays, etc) is also managed by the GC.  If, however, you create a bunch of `Memory` objects and maintain references to them, they won't be GC'd and the native memory they represent won't ever be freed (that memory is invisible to the Java heap).

Comment: @technomage   So you suggest that the only way to create native memory leaks with jna and the user32.dll is when I keep references to returned buffers/memory ? Anything else will be released and there is no need for me to free something by hand? Given that I never alloc anything by myself - only using arrays, integers and Memory objects inside the java world.

Comment: If native code returns some form of allocated memory, you need to explicitly free it by some subsequent native call (e.g. pair every `malloc` with a corresponding `free`).

Comment: @technomage ok, I got that. But when I never use "malloc" by myself and only pass Memory objects from the Java world, do I need to free anything? If so - how do I know what function delivers me allocated memory I need to free myself?

Comment: This is a pointless conversation since `SendMessageA` returns nothing but a primitive int (stack-allocated).

Comment: You have to rely on the w32 API documentation.  If all you're calling is `SendMessageA`, then no, there is no memory allocation.  To track down the leak, you might try selectively eliminating certain bits of your functionality (e.g. returning a fixed String instead of doing a lookup).  This is most effectively done if you can split the code in two to do a binary search.